# Is it possible to get a code review of scripts while obfuscating sensitive information?

Tags: discussion

Namely, I wrote a Python script to handle Cloudflare-based Dynamic DNS updates for a system, but I need to obfuscate my CloudFlare creds and some API keys, for fairly obvious reasons. Would there be any problem in posting a code review with full code but obfuscating those credentials?